# Return null in a method that returns doubles java

Tags: java, null

I am trying to test for a null input at the start of the method. And if found true I want to return null even though the method would usually return doubles.

I need to keep the type of method as double

```
public double computeMean (double[] grades) {
        if (grades == null) {
            return null;
```

> Cannot convert from null to double

Comment: You could make the return type `Double` to make it `null`-compatible.

Comment: Exactly as the error says. You cannot return `null` where a primitive is expected. You could if the method signature would be for a `Double`, though.

Comment: You can either change the return type to `Double`, or maybe return `Double.NaN`.

Comment: Or `throw new IllegalArgumentException("computeMean on null array is illegal.");`

Answer (score 4):

### Explanation

`null` is a value that can only be used for objects. A `double` however is a primitive, it does not use the object-system. Which is why you can not return `null` if you specified `double` as return type.

So, what are your options?

---

### `Double` wrapper

You can instead use `Double`, the wrapper class for `double` which uses the object-system.

Since Java provides automatic conversion between `double` and `Double` whenever needed (autoboxing), this can be quite handy to use.

Note that using `Double` brings quite some overhead to just a small `double` and that people regularly tend to forget to check for `null` when converting a `Double` to a `double`. I.e.

```
// foo() returns Double
double value = foo(); // Bad code, it could be null!
```

Instead, users must remember to check the resulting value:

```
Double result = foo();
if (result == null) {
    ...
} else {
    double value = result;
    ...
}
```

---

### `OptionalDouble`

The modern, and probably better alternative, is to use `Optional` (you need at least Java 8 for this).

It was designed to be used whenever a method naturally might sometimes not return a result. For example if the array passed in **empty**. That case is completely okay and not to be considered as error.

This also solves the problem of users forgetting to check the result. `Optional` forces them to check it, else they can not get hands on the underlying value.

In order to avoid the performance overhead of `Optional<Double>` (wrapper class again), there is also `OptionalDouble` which internally uses `double` (primitive). Here is the code:

```
public OptionalDouble computeMean(double[] grades) {
    if (grades == null) {
        return OptionalDouble.empty();
    }
    ...
    return OptionalDouble.of(result);
}
```

And the usage:

```
OptionalDouble result = computeMean(...);
```

From there the user has a couple of options (see the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/OptionalDouble.html)), for example

```
double value = result.orElse(10.4);
// or
double value = result.orElseThrow();
// or
if (!result.isPresent()) {
    ...
} else {
    double value = result.getAsDouble();
}
```

---

### Exception

The last option is to actually just throw an exception. You should consider this whenever an user is doing something that is not intended and against what you consider correct usage (indicate this in your methods documentation).

I would actually say that in your specific situation, this is the case. It is impossible to compute a `mean` on `null`. It is different to passing in an empty array, where the I would go for an empty `Optional`. For a `null` array I would throw an exception, to indicate a bad usage.

A good exception for this situation is `IllegalArgumentException`, here is the code:

```
public double computeMean(double[] grades) {
    if (grades == null) {
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Grades must not be null!");
    }
    ...
}
```

Another idiomatic exception for exactly this use case is to throw `NullPointerException`. There is even a compact helper method to do all of this in one line:

```
public double computeMean(double[] grades) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(grades); // Yes, thats it

    ...
}
```

---

### Result

Putting all of that together, I would do the following two changes:

- Throw `NullPointerException` if `grades` is `null`, using `Objects#requireNonNull`
- Return an empty `OptionalDouble` if `grades` is empty

```
public OptionalDouble computeMean(double[] grades) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(grades);

    if (grades.length == 0) {
        return OptionalDouble.empty();
    }

    ...
    return OptionalDouble.of(result);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use

> `Double` wrapper class(mind the uppercase "d")

not `double` primitive type as your return type, if you want to be able to return `null`.

Comment: I would throw an exception. This is an error case. Or otherwise return an empty `OptionalDouble`, if it is considered a correct usage of the method. Returning `null` seems like a bad choice for various reasons. And it feels so not-modern style.